# How do I render each time increment on Premiere Pro CS5/6?

Tags: premiere, video-editor, automation, cs6, cs5

I want to write a script that automates rendering in a way that each, say, 30 seconds of a longer video becomes a separate video file. How do I approach this without having to manually highlight and render each time increment?

Comment: Does it have to be with Premiere? This kind of job suits a command line application like ffmpeg.

Comment: It can be done with FFMPEG?

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly suggest outputting the whole thing to a lossless format and then using another tool to split the file.  Depending on if you have audio, it could be particularly easy to do by exporting as an image sequence and simply moving and renaming the images for each 30 second clip and then encoding each.  If they have audio, then you'd want to actually use something like FFMpeg for splitting the file though.

Comment: The file would have audio, yes.

Comment: I do like that image sequence idea. I'll keep that in mind for another project.